# Swift if/else statement Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a game written in Swift using sprite kit, I'd like the game to become for difficult after the score variable is greater than 30 and i want the "d" to decrease by .5, the current code for the speed is:

```
    let d = CGFloat.random(min:2.0, max:3.0)
```

Comment: you cannot change d as you declare it as a constant, however you can decrease the place here d is use by another value that indicates the difficult, lets say var currentDifficult = d - level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `update()` method you can make

```
if score >= 30 {
    //increase speed
    //decrease d
}
```

**Note**

You have to change the declaration of `d` to `var d = /*your code*/` instead of using `let` which declares it as constant. `var` makes it a variable which is changeable.

Hope that helps :)